# Why does select error occur near this statement?

Tags: r, database, sqlite, select, syntax

I am running this Sqlite query in R using aggregations to find the lastPrice column for this stock data.

The error is occurring on the third SELECT statement and I am unable to determine why.  I have tried this multiple ways and have pulled about the units, but it still doesn't work. The idea is to find the lastPrice column for each time bucket, but it is not giving me the correct result.

Here is the original error message:

```
Error: near "SELECT": syntax error
```

Comment: Don't post photos of your code. Post your code directly.

Comment: Also be more descriptive. What does "it doesn't work actually mean"

Comment: @Dason, thank you for your comment.  I tired posting my code and formatting it, but it would not accept it.

Comment: @Dason, I was unable to post the actual error message in the title. I am new at this, so please be a bit more patient with my process.  I do appreciate your feedback.  Here is the original error message. Error: near "SELECT": syntax error

Comment: Bruce, please consider where we're coming from: we don't know your data, your error/warning, or your expected output. At a minimum, include *real text* (not images) and *actual error messages*. It is better to give a more-complete minimal working example with forming a sample database and executing a real (representative) query on it with the same (erring) results you have.

Comment: Error should go in the text of the question, just click the `edit` link below/left from the question *body*.

Comment: @r2evans I will do that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL CTE syntax is incorrect: you have a comma after the last CTE's close-paren. The only time you need a comma there is if you have another CTE following it.

Try changing to

```sql
with unit as (
  select t.RefDate, ...
),                                        -- yes comma here, between CTEs
agg as (
  select u.RefDate, ...
)                                         -- no comma here, after the last CTE
select u.RefDate, u.Symbol, ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful responses and edits to my last post.  I am now receiving this message when I run the rest of the code, after your suggestions: Error: near "AGG": syntax error.  I thought that the "," was required between these statements.

Comment: The comma is required *between* CTEs, but not after the last one. (My answer is consistent with that, are your commas similar to my answer?)

Comment: yes they are consistent with your response.

Comment: I found the error.  Thank you so much for your help with this and for the direction on posting. I learned a lot from you.

Comment: Glad you found the error! (Was it a mis-placed comma or something completely different?)

Comment: It was the misplaced comma. Thank you, again.

Comment: I also noticed that two people voted a -1 for one of my posts.  SO has recommended that I not post for another 5 days.  Is that some kind of penalty?  I was unable ask someone else, so I hope it's okay to ask you here.

Comment: Bruce, I can think of two reasons your question was downvoted: (1) image of code/data is strongly discouraged and typically not as helpful (and you started with two copies of the same image, further clutter); and related, (2) you did not provide text of code and the actual text of the error until late in the game. Downvoters do not received notifications when a question is edited, and there is little reason/impetus to revisit and potentially un-downvote. The "no post for 5d" thing is a bot-thing to encourage improving desired behavior/traits (though I'm not a moderator).

Comment: That is clear and I will do better next time.  Your feedback is very valuable and I appreciate your thoughtful response.  I would like to delete the question entirely, but it appears that I am unable to do so.